# How to remove Music from a song and keep Vocals

Tags: audacity

I Have a movie sample with audio transcription (For Blind People- There is a narrator explaining what is going on in the movie). I want to extract that.

What i so far tried was:

1- I have the sample without the transcription as well so i just imported both samples in Audacity. Inverted one and mixed. But it simply doesnt work ( Normalization is also applied)

2- I tooke the sample with audio description. splitted to mono, Took one channel and inverted. and mixed again. Now i have the movie without audio transcript. My intuition was that if i invert  this result file again and mix it with the Actual one the other sounds should cross out and i would have the Narrator sound. But it did not happen! what shall i do now ? any suggestions ?

I have checked the following links so far :

http://www.howtogeek.com/61250/how-to-isolate-and-save-vocals-from-music-tracks-using-audacity/

http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/remove-vocals-song-mp3-music-instruments/1301/